# How to convert c# list of list after i pass it to the view?

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net-mvc

I already pass the list of list from controller to my view using ViewBag. The list have 2 items, each item have 8 sub items. I expect my console.log is showing an array of array but it is showing as below in google chrome.
 -> System.Collections.Generic.List`1[System.Collections.Generic.List`1[System.String]].

Please help me,i don't know how to convert it to array of array.

Appreciate your help. Thanks.

```
<script>

      $(document).ready(function () {

           serverItem = '@ViewBag.serverItems';

           console.log(serverItem);

           });

</script>
```

Comment: @mjwills I want it to be like this [[1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8],[1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8]]. I want to assign the value to serverItem variable in my javascript.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you have an object in the server side and you need to use it on the javascript scope, you have to transfer it by rendering. You have to provide a format that are compatible to both, in this case, `json` is a good choice. For sample:

On the `razor`, you define a string object with the json format. (remember to add the `Newtonsoft.Json` namespace)

```
@{ 
    var json = @Html.Raw(Json.Encode(ViewBag.serverItems)); 
}
```

In the javascript, you just print the json and it will be a javascript object.

```
<script>

      $(document).ready(function () {

           serverItem = @json;

           console.log(serverItem);

           });

</script>
```